# How can I calculate the total value of amount due after choosing different option from drop-down list?

Tags: javascript

I tried some codes, but none worked. I have an amount due that should change when the quantity number from the drop-down list changes. So if someone changes the number of order it should multiply by the base number of desktop and the result should be the total amount. Here is part of my code which I think is relative to calculation part.

```js
var amountDue = document.getElementById("amountDue");
var desktopAddOns = document.querySelectorAll(".products");
var total = 0;
var price = 0;

//Removes the add on options from view
document.getElementById("desktops").onchange = function () {
    if (document.getElementById("desktops").checked) {
        price = 185;
    } else if (document.getElementById("desktops").checked == false) {
        price = 185;
        removeAddOns(price);
    }
    addAddOns(price);
};

computerType.onchange = function () {
    document.getElementById("desktops").checked = false;

};

function addAddOns(price) {
    total += price;
    amountDue.innerHTML = total;
}

function removeAddOns(price) {
    total -= price * 2;
    amountDue.innerHTML = total;
}
```

```html
<div class=" products">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="chkYes1">
            <input type="checkbox" id="desktops" name="" value="desktops" />
            desktop $185.00 &nbsp;&nbsp;
        </label>
    </div>
    <select id="selectbasic" name="" class="">
        <option value="1">0</option>
        <option value="2">1</option>
        <option value="3">2</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div class="form-group border border-dark rounded py-3 px-5">
    <h3>Amount Due: <p id="amountDue">0</p>
    </h3>
</div>
```

Comment: do you want to calculate the desktop amount with the number selected from dropdown list & then output the results, correct?

Comment: Yes, That is what I am trying to do.

Comment: Did it work for you? Accept my answer if it does please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution:

- **First**, remove this code snippet since it's currently throwing an error:

```
computerType.onchange = function () {
    document.getElementById("desktops").checked = false;
};
```

- **Second**, declare these two variables to store the **`<select>`** tag element & the future **`selected`** value like so:

```
var selectOptions = document.getElementById("ddlViewBy");
var selectedValue;
```

- **Third**, add this method to get the `selected` value & multiply the total like so:

```
selectOptions.addEventListener('change', () => {
    selectedValue =  selectOptions.options[ selectOptions.selectedIndex].value;

    amountDue.innerHTML = Math.round(total * selectedValue);
})
```

For your reference, here is the full code sample:

```
var amountDue = document.getElementById("amountDue");
var desktopAddOns = document.querySelectorAll(".products");

var selectOptions = document.getElementById("selectbasic");
var selectedValue;

var total = 0;
var price = 0;

//Removes the add on options from view
document.getElementById("desktops").onchange = function () {
  if (document.getElementById("desktops").checked) {
    price = 185;
  } else if (document.getElementById("desktops").checked == false) {
    price = 185;
    removeAddOns(price);
  }
  addAddOns(price);
};

//amountDue.innerHTML += total;
function addAddOns(price) {
  total += price;
  amountDue.innerHTML = total;
}
function removeAddOns(price) {
  total -= price * 2;
  amountDue.innerHTML = total;
}

selectOptions.addEventListener('change', () => {
  selectedValue =  selectOptions.options[ selectOptions.selectedIndex].value;

  amountDue.innerHTML = Math.round(total * selectedValue);
})
```

You can also **[check this working code sample](https://jsfiddle.net/8z7f6yvs/)**.

If you have questions about the code, let me know.

Comment: Your code works. but when I added it to my project, it gives me unexpected results. I add a [jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/samsh/76vhndz2/1/) . So after clicking the checkbox and change the quantity if I select something from extra items, the total will reset to the base price = 185 (quantity = 1)

Comment: It it works please accept my answer since formally answer your question. If you need further assistance, open a new question with the error reference for your expecific case.

Comment: @Sam thanks. let me know when you post your next question. I'll try to help you

Comment: [Hers is the rest of the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58585700/how-can-get-the-total-values-of-check-boxes-and-selected-value-of-a-dropdown-lis) Thanks in advance