# Get the total values of check boxes and selected value of a dropdown list in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I set the dropdown to zero. Is it possible to change it to one, once the first checkbox is clicked? The other problem is the calculation. So after clicking the checkbox and change the quantity (let's say I choose quantity= 2, so the amount due will be 370)if I select something from extra items, the amount of the desktop will reset to the base price = 185 (quantity = 1)

```js
var amountDue = document.getElementById("amountDue");
var desktopAddOns = document.querySelectorAll(".products");

var selectOptions = document.getElementById("selectbasic");
var selectedValue;

var total = 0;
var price = 0;

//Removes the add on options from view
document.getElementById("desktops").onchange = function () {
  if (document.getElementById("desktops").checked) {
    price = 185;
  } else if (document.getElementById("desktops").checked == false) {
    price = 185;
    removeAddOns(price);
  }
  addAddOns(price);
};
document.getElementById("wirelessCard").onchange = function () {
    if (document.getElementById("wirelessCard").checked) {
        price = 30;
    } else if (document.getElementById("wirelessCard").checked == false) {
        price = 30;
        removeAddOns(price);
    }
    addAddOns(price);
};
//amountDue.innerHTML += total;
function addAddOns(price) {
  total += price;
  amountDue.innerHTML = total;
}
function removeAddOns(price) {
  total -= price * 2;
  amountDue.innerHTML = total;
}

selectOptions.addEventListener('change', () => {
  selectedValue =  selectOptions.options[ selectOptions.selectedIndex].value;

  amountDue.innerHTML = Math.round(total * selectedValue);
})
```

```html
<div class=" products">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="chkYes1">
            <input type="checkbox" id="desktops" name="" value="desktops" />
            desktop $185.00 &nbsp;&nbsp;
        </label>
    </div>
    <select id="selectbasic" name="" class="">
        <option value="1">0</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
    </select>
</div><br>


                <label class=" font-weight-bold" for="checkboxes">Extra Items for Purchase
                    (Desktop)</label>
                <div>
                    <div class="extraItemsDesktop">
                        <label for="checkboxes-0">
                            <input type="checkbox" name="wirelessCard" id="wirelessCard" value="wirelessCard">
                            Wireless Card - $30.00
                        </label>
                    </div>


<div class="form-group border border-dark rounded py-3 px-5">
    <h3>Amount Due: <p id="amountDue">0</p>
    </h3>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below modified code:

```js
var amountDue = document.getElementById("amountDue");
var desktopAddOns = document.querySelectorAll(".products");

var selectOptions = document.getElementById("selectbasic");

function calculateTotal() {
  var oDesktopAddOn = document.getElementById("desktops");
  var oWirelessCardAddOn = document.getElementById("wirelessCard");
  var dTotal = 0;

  if (oDesktopAddOn.checked) {
    dTotal += 185;

    var iNumberofItems = selectOptions.options[selectOptions.selectedIndex].value;
    dTotal = Math.round(dTotal * iNumberofItems);
  }

  if (oWirelessCardAddOn.checked) {
    dTotal += 30;
  }

  amountDue.innerHTML = dTotal;
}

document.getElementById("desktops").addEventListener("change", function() {
  selectOptions.value = 1;
  calculateTotal();
});
document.getElementById("wirelessCard").addEventListener("change", calculateTotal)
selectOptions.addEventListener('change', calculateTotal);
```

```html
<div class=" products">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="chkYes1">
            <input type="checkbox" id="desktops" name="" value="desktops" />
            desktop $185.00 &nbsp;&nbsp;
        </label>
  </div>
  <select id="selectbasic" name="" class="">
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
  </select>
</div><br>


<label class=" font-weight-bold" for="checkboxes">Extra Items for Purchase
                    (Desktop)</label>
<div>
  <div class="extraItemsDesktop">
    <label for="checkboxes-0">
                            <input type="checkbox" name="wirelessCard" id="wirelessCard" value="wirelessCard">
                            Wireless Card - $30.00
                        </label>
  </div>


  <div class="form-group border border-dark rounded py-3 px-5">
    <h3>Amount Due:
      <p id="amountDue">0</p>
    </h3>
  </div>
```